# APK Upload failed on Google Play Console

Tags: android, upload, apk, google-play-console

i am trying to upload an APK file to the Google Play Console. But this fails again and again. I get the message "Error while uploading. Please try again." I have already deleted the browser data in my browser and tried other browsers. Even the incognito mode did nothing. I have also tried to change the Package ID. This is the first version of the app. There is no previous version. The error comes in a Swiss Google Play Console account. On a German account I can upload the APK's that could not be uploaded without problems. Is there maybe a Geo-Lock here? That I can only upload APK's from Switzerland on the Swiss account? Or are there no restrictions?
[Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uawHT.png)

Comment: are you sure upload realse build and try to upload app bundel

Comment: Yes, it is a Xamarin.Android App. I choose Release in Visual Studio before I start the build. But I think that this is not the mistake, because on another account (German Account) can i upload the APK without problems but not on the Swiss account.

Comment: @Amitpandey i try again with the App Bundel. Here i also get the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for your help. I have now waited a few days and tried to upload the .APK again. This time it worked without problems. I haven't made any changes since then and also used the first version I built. Could have been Google itself. In the current situation everything just doesn't work anywhere the way you wanted it to. :D
Thanks again and stay healthy. :)

Answer (score 0):

Select Artifact Library option from Drawer. Check the folder, There must be an apk/bundle with same version name and code. Delete this or use if you want to add new build or try to add new apk with updated version.